# Page not found (404)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.5

После запуска сервера django, и перехода на страницу localhost:8000/lesson-third/view/ появляется следующая ошибка в браузере: *Page not found (404)*. Django переустанавливал, не помогло. Попробовал добавить другой url, всё равно появляется та же ошибка. Как решить данную проблему?

**courses_django/settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for courses_django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p@8k2c(&6&2q-*ak+b6blic@$%%^%@-cckn^+(vp(sy9m60t@%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lesson_one',
    'lesson_two',
    'lesson_two_part2',
    'lesson_two_response',
    'lesson_third',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'courses_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'courses_django.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
'
```

**courses_django/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.contrib import admin
# from lesson_two import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'', include('lesson_one.urls')),
    # path(r'^ admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^', views.home),
    # url(r'^', include('lesson_two.urls')),
    # url(r'^', include('lesson_two_part2.urls')),
    # url(r'^lesson-two-response/', include('lesson_two_response.urls')),
    url(r'^lesson-third/', include('lesson_third.urls')),
]
```

**lesson_third/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime, math
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader


# Create your views here.

def view(request):
    list = [0, 232, 4, 555, 654, 54, 12]
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
        "test": "TEXT",
        "list": list,
        "name": "ALEX",
        "surname": "Ivanov",
        "coords": {
            "x": "x coords",
            "y": "y coords",
        },
        'list': [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**lesson_third/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view$', views.view)
]
```

**templates/index.html:**

```
{% load poll_extras %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        ol.variables li, ol.filters li span {
            font-size: 32px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello 3 lesson</h1>
<h2>{{test}}</h2>
<h2>Variables:</h2>

    <ol clas="variables">
        <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
        <li>Surname: {{surname}}</li>
        <li>Coords.x: {{coords.x}}</li>
        <li>Coords.y: {{coords.y}}</li>
        <li>list[0]: {{qwerty}}</li>
        <li></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

**В консоли выводиться следующее**:

```
Not Found: /lesson-third/view/
[12/Nov/2018 14:17:28] "GET /lesson-third/view/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2231
```

Comment: В логах при этом должен появится traceback. Его полный текст надо добавить в вопрос.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, добавил. Всё добавить не смог, потому что всё то, что выше добавил несколько раз повторяется.

Comment: Похоже, у вас повреждён модуль Django. Попробуйте переустановить.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev удалил с помощью команды "pip unistal django" и установил "pip install django". Сейчас в браузере, появляется другая ошибка: "Page not found (404)", когда перехожу на http://localhost:8000/lesson-third/view/

Comment: У вас в пути `^view$` указан символ доллара - конец строки. `/lesson/view` будет работать, а `/lesson/view/` - нет. Просто уберите последний слэш или добавьте его в урл.

Comment: @floydya огромное вам спасибо. Теперь всё работает, добавте ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы вам начислили баллы.